# XCode, driverkit: __debug file not found for <memory>, <vector> and some other includes

Tags: xcode, driverkit

I have XCode 15.0 project with dext target (C++).

Including of <memory>, <vector> and some other headers causes compilation error: __debug file not found.

Base SDK and Supported platforms: DriverKit.

But there are no such problems for other C++ targets inside the project - command line tools, etc.

I know there are some restrictions for system extensions - direct file access, interprocess communication,

but this problem looks like a bug, or misconfiguration of my system.

Reinstallation of XCode didn't help, as well as __debug file copy to DriverKit framework headers folder.

Comment: The DriverKit SDK and runtime do not contain complete C++ and C standard libraries. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820426/48660).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding a link to __debug file into the list of project sources. May be not portable solution for different SDK versions, but working.